# What Is the probability of getting all $17$ numbers out of a set of $11$ and $12$?

Tags: probability

I have an urn with balls labeled $1$ through $17$ inside of it. I first pick $11$ balls without replacing them in between and record which numbers I picked. I then put them all back in and pick $12$ balls using the same method. My question is, what is the probability that I will pick one ball with each number on it?
I have attempted to make an excel spreadsheet to estimate what the answer would be, but I am interested in getting the precise answer. Another way of thinking about it which could help is by asking, what is the probability that there will be exactly $6$ duplicate picks?

Comment: Imagine the balls were originally painted white.  Go ahead and pick the first 11 balls and paint the balls red.  *It doesn't matter to us which balls those were*.  Regardless which balls they were, we are now in the situation of an urn with $17$ balls... $11$ of which are red and $6$ of which are white.  You are picking $12$ balls out of this urn and you ask the probability that you picked all six white balls within those $12$.  This is a quintessential [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) problem.

Comment: The answer is very simply $\dfrac{\binom{11}{6}\binom{6}{6}}{\binom{17}{12}}=\dfrac{33}{442}\approx 0.07466$

Comment: " My question is, what is the probability that I will pick one ball with each number on it?"   Please elaborate!

Comment: As a nitpick, in your title, you used the word *odds* and in the body you used *probability*.  Do not confuse these two words.  They are not equivalent.  They are related, yes, and they convey the same information... however the format in which they convey the information is different.  While the probability is $\dfrac{33}{442}$, the *odds* would have been $33:419$.  The probability is effectively the ratio of a number of times we see it happen vs the total number of attempts.  The odds on the other hand is the ratio of number of times we see it happen vs number of times it doesn't happen.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for your solution and your elegant way of describing it. If you make it an answer I will accept it. Your nitpick is noted. Should I edit the title?

Comment: @herbsteinberg perhaps it would have been more accurate to say, what is the probability that I will pick **at least** one ball with each number from 1 to 17 (and 6 of them twice)?

Comment: " at least one ball with each number from 1 to 17"  i.e. pick each ball at least once, so six balls have been picked twice.  (I am guessing English is not your native language.)

Comment: @JMoravitz That was such a brilliant explanation! Truly! How can I train my brain to think like this? I'm truly shook, any pointers would be a blessing!

Comment: In R, `dhyper(6, 6,11, 12)` returns $0.07466063,$ agreeing with @JMoravits' comutation.